# Google Script: Search Drive for filenames (from csv), add to another folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a script which performs the following:

I have a Google Sheet which contains a variable number of file names (could be 10, could be 1,000). I need to read this sheet and for each entry, search My Drive (and shared with me) and add the item to another folder on My Drive (same function as pressing Shift+Z).

I currently have a script which searches Drive and provides the url, but this takes user input, takes one expression at a time and does not "add to" another folder.

Comment: show the code you already tried. not just your old code but an attempt to solve what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Use the [makeCopy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String,Folder)) method:

```
makeCopy(name, destination)
```

`destination` is the directory to copy the file into.  The `destination` parameter is *not* a string.  It's a `folder` *type*.

Comment: this doesnt answer the question just one part (which in my opinion the question is too broad)

Comment: The person posting the question may be capable of deciding whether this answers their question or not.

Comment: and so can any s.o. user.

Comment: If you think the question asks too many things and you dont feel like answering the entire question, feel free to add your hint as a comment. but this clearly does not answer the question and any user is entitled to point that out. Your other option is to flag the question which I did.

Comment: Am I free and entitled to try to answer the question?

Comment: and who said you arent? has anybody deleted your question? Just like you can answer anything you want, any user can comment anything they want. What is your point? I didnt even flag of downvoted your answer,

Comment: Please note that as a Google Expert on Apps Script I am not only entitled to comment anything I wish (just like any other user), but it is also my duty to keep the apps script tag clean. cheers. https://developers.google.com/experts/people/zig-mandel

Comment: You're using the comment section for a personal discussion about how to handle the situation.